# Multipage form progress indicator

Tags: webforms

How would I go about adding a **progress indicator** to my multi page form?

So for example, I would like to have a Heading at the top of each of the form pages/stages. I would like them all to be displayed at all times, but with a "status box" or something similar next to each status, which changes once a certain stage has been completed (all the mandatory fields have been populated).

Any advice on how to achieve this?

Comment: you can achieve progress indicator on webform with help of javascript. You can follow the example given here http://envisioninteractive.com/web-development/breaking-drupal-7-webforms-into-multiple-steps-the-easy-way/

Answer (score 2):

Taken from Bala's answer.  I had to do a great deal of work on the code before it worked so I thought I'd paste my corrected code here:

Copy sites/all/modules/webform/templates/webform-form.tpl.php to your sites/all/themes/ folder so that you don't hack the original tpl.

In the sites/all/themes//webform-form.tpl.php copy add the code:

```
<?php
    if($form['details']['page_count']['#value'] > 1){
        $output_pagenum = '<div class="page-count">Page '
            . '<span class="actual">' . $form['details']['page_num']['#value'] . '</span>' . ' of '
            . '<span class="total">' . $form['details']['page_count']['#value'] . '</span>';
        echo $output_pagenum . '</div>';
        // End of custom code
    }

  // Print out the main part of the form.
  // Feel free to break this up and move the pieces within the array.
  print drupal_render($form['submitted']);

  // Always print out the entire $form. This renders the remaining pieces of the
  // form that haven't yet been rendered above.
  print drupal_render($form);
```

Then in your js file:

```
//Progress bar for webforms.
    var actual = $('.actual').text(); //Get the value of the actual page.
    var total = $('.total').text(); //Get the value of the total of pages.

    if(total > 1) { // check if is a single page form and the webform has no breaks
        var percentage = (actual/total)*100; //Divides the actual value between all the pages.
        percentage = percentage + '%';
        var progressbar = '<div id="progress-container" style="background:#c2c2c2;">'
         + '<div id="progressbar" style="margin-top:10px;background:#762C39;min-height:15px;"></div></div>';

        $('.page-count').append(progressbar);
        $('#progressbar').css('width', percentage); //Depending on which page break youre on modifies the width of the progress bar.
    }

    //End of Progress Bar
```

Answer (score 1):

Open sites/all/modules/webform/templates/webform.tpl.php and add this code

```
<?php
//Add this ..
$output_pagenum = ‘<div>Page ‘
. ‘ActualPage”>’ . $form['details']['page_num']['#value'] . ‘‘ . ‘ of ‘
. ‘TotalPage”>’ . $form['details']['page_count']['#value'] . ‘‘;
echo $output_pagenum;
// End of custom code

// Print out the main part of the form.
// Feel free to break this up and move the pieces within the array.
print drupal_render($form['submitted']);
```

Add the below code to script.js file, by adding scripts[] = js/script.js in your .info file and place the script.js in your theme folder -> js folder -> script.js

```
(function ($, Drupal, window, document, undefined) {
$(document).ready(function() {
//Progress bar for webforms.
$actual = jQuery(‘.ActualPage’).text(); //Get the value of the actual page.
$total = jQuery(‘.TotalPage’).text(); //Get the value of the total of pages.
$percentage = ($actual/$total)*100; //Divides the actual value between all the pages.
$percentage = $percentage+’%';
$progressbar = ‘<div id=”progressbarContainer” style=”background:#c2c2c2;”><div id=”progressbar” style=”background:#a3a3a3;min-height:15px;”></div></div>’
jQuery(‘.page-count’).append($progressbar)
jQuery(‘#progressbar’).css({‘width’: $percentage}); //Depending on which page break youre on modifies the width of the progress bar.
// check if is a single page form or the webform has no breaks
if($actual == 1 &amp;&amp; $total == 1) {
$(‘.page-count’).remove();
}
//End of Progress Bar
});

})(jQuery, Drupal, this, this.document);
```

[image]

Taken from the source [Progress bar webform with page breaks Drupal 7](http://isramv.wordpress.com/2013/03/08/progress-bar-webform-with-page-breaks-drupal-7/)

Comment: Contrib and core module code should never be altered directly ...